# replace page number in url without reloading

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out how to replace a page number in my URL when ajax page loading. Here's what I have right now:

```
var current_url = window.location.href;
var replaced_url = current_url.toString();
new_url = replaced_url.replace("/page=\d+/", "page="+page);
history.pushState('page'+page, document.title, new_url);
```

Problem is, the page number never gets replaced.

Testing it on a URL like:

```
http://127.0.0.1/2020/09/some-title-here/page=2#comments
```

It just always says page=2, it's never replace - why?

Comment: What does `new_url` return?

Comment: The exact same URL it's fed, the replace just doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to replace a static string with another string, rather than using RegEx, don't stringify the RegEx format: `replaced_url.replace(/page=\d+/, "page=" + page)`

```js
var current_url = "http://127.0.0.1/2020/09/some-title-here/page=2#comments";

var replaced_url = current_url.toString();

var new_url = replaced_url.replace(/page=\d+/, "page=69");

console.log(new_url);
```